# Selenium scraping

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to come up with a way to scrape information on houses on Zillow and I am currently using xpath to look at data such as rent price, principal and mortgage costs, insurance costs.

I was able to find the information using xpath but I wanted to make it automatic and put it inside a for loop but I realized as I was using xpath, not all the data for each listing has the same xpath information. for some it would be off by 1 of a list or div. See code below for what I mean. How do I get it more specific? Is there a way to look up for a string like "principal and interest" and select the next value which would be the numerical value that I am looking for?

works for one listing:

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[1]/**div[1]**/ul/li[1]/article/div[1]/div[2]/div")

a different listing would contain this:

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/div[1]/**div[2]**/ul/li[1]/article/div[1]/div[2]/div")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpaths that you are using are specific to the elements of the first listing. To be able to access elements for each listing, you will need to use xpaths in a way that can help you access elements for each listing:

```
import pandas as pd    
from selenium import webdriver
```

I searched for listing for sale in Manhattan and got the below URL
url = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/Manhattan,-New-York,-NY_rb/"

Asking selenium to open the above link in Chrome

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
```

I hovered my mouse on one of the house listings and clicked "inspect". This opened the HTML code and highlighted the item I am inspecting. I noticed that the elements having class "list-card-info" contain all the info of the house that we need. So, our strategy would be for each house access the element that has class "list-card-info". So, using the following code, I saved all such HTML blocks in house_cards variable

```
house_cards = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("list-card-info")
```

There are 40 elements in house_cards i.e. one for each house (each page has 40 houses listed)

I loop over each of these 40 houses and extract the information I need. Notice that I am now using xpaths which are specific to elements within the "list-card-info" element. I save this info in a pandas datagram.

```
address = []
price = []
bedrooms = []
baths = []
sq_ft = []

for house in house_cards:
    address.append(house.find_element_by_class_name("list-card-addr").text)
    price.append(house.find_element_by_class_name("list-card-price").text)
    bedrooms.append(house.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="list-card-heading"]/ul[@class="list-card-details"]/li[1]').text)
    baths.append(house.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="list-card-heading"]/ul[@class="list-card-details"]/li[2]').text)
    sq_ft.append(house.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="list-card-heading"]/ul[@class="list-card-details"]/li[3]').text)
driver.quit()



# print(address, price,bedrooms,baths, sq_ft)
Manahattan_listings = pd.DataFrame({"address":address,
                                    "bedrooms": bedrooms,
                                    "baths":baths,
                                    "sq_ft":sq_ft,
                                    "price":price},)
```

[pandas dataframe output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6WNy.png)

Now, to extract info from more pages i.e. page2, page 3, etc, you can loop over website pages i.e. keep modifying your URL and keep extracting info

Happy **Scraping**!

Comment: This was super helpful. Thank you so much. Do you use jupyter notebook for this? I've never used pandas before, how do you grab each individual number? Would it be the same way as accessing each index of an array (i.e. price[1]). What are your resources you use to learn more about pandas/selelnium and web scraping if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Yes, I use Jupyter Notebooks. Navigating pandas is similar to navigating arrays; you use [ ] brackets. You can also use .iloc and .loc methods as well. I would recommend you to watch a video on this as this is really simple stuff. I learn everything from googling, maybe watch/do an online video/course on python basics to get started. I am also a beginner (but have 6 months of learning). I was stuck on web scrapping for three days, but I kept searching on google and in fact did a course on datacamp as well. So yeah, just keep digging and you will figure it out. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate all the tips and good luck to you as well!

Answer (score 0):

selecting multiple elements using xpath is not a good idea. You can look into "css selector". Using this you can get similar elements.